# Substitute function for pandas read_table not working

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas, scipy

I am new to Python!
Due to some reasons, I can not use pandas in my environment. So I am writing the pandas read_table() by myself. Basically I am converting one code which is using pandas.read_table by myself. The code using pandas which has to be replaced is as follows :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
data_file = pd.read_table(r'records.csv', sep = ';', header=None)

id = np.unique(data_file[0])
tags = np.unique(data_file[1])

number_of_rows = len(id)
number_of_columns = len(tags)

words_indices, letter_indices = {}, {}

for i in range(len(tags)):
     words_indices[tags[i]] = i

for i in range(len(id)):
     letter_indices[id[i]] = i


#scipy sparse matrix 
Vector = sp.lil_matrix((number_of_rows, number_of_columns))

#adds data into the sparse matrix
for line in data_file.values:
     u, i , r = map(str,line)
     Vector[letter_indices[u], words_indices[i]] = r
```

The csv file is having some 100 records of this format :

```
REC000034232657,CRC FIX OE Resubmit,0.0073410, 45
```

Now, I have replaced the pandas.read_table as follows by directly reading it from database rather than from .csv file :

```
def fetch_table(**kwargs):
    qry = kwargs['qrystr']
    try:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(qry)
        all_tuples  = cursor.fetchall()
        return all_tuples
    except pyodbc.ProgrammingError as e:
        print ("Exception occured as :",  type(e) , e)

# pandas alternate code
total_col = 0
count = 0
dict_csv = {}

stmt = "select * from tickets;"
fetched_rows = fetch_table(qrystr = stmt)

for row in fetched_rows:
    total_col = len(row)
    break

for i in range(0,total_col):
    dict_csv[i] = []

for row in fetched_rows:
    for i in range(0,total_col):
        dict_csv[i].append(row[i])

# End of pandas alternate code
```

Rest of the code just continues to be same as the earlier chunk of code except that instead of data_file (returned by pd.read_table()), now I am using dict_csv , so the for loop in the earlier code which adds data to the sparse matrix is  changed to :

```
 for line in data_file.values:
         u, i , r = map(str,line)
         Vector[letter_indices[u], words_indices[i]] = r
```

However, I am getting below TypeError for that :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\my_scripts\ds.py", line 132, in <module>
    for line in dict_csv.values:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

I understand that dict_csv.values is not returning an iterable list, can anybody please point me what mistake I am making.
Also the integer 45 is coming as Decimal(45), how can I get rid of that ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You are missing the parens to call the actual method  `dict_csv.values() <- add parens`

Comment: correcting that gives another error as :  u, i , r = map(str,line)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3), is it related to my mistake ?

Comment: No, it means you have more than three values after mapping line to str, why are you mapping to str in the first place?